# Why did Sprite get Acheron drunk?

Tags: acheron, dark-hunter, atlantis

I recently reread the Dark Hunter book about their leader named Acheron. In this book you learn that he cannot get drunk from beer because he is an Atlantean God. **So why was it that towards the end of the book, when Tory gave him some of her Sprite, did he start to get buzzed and then act drunk**.

I don't recall there being anything in the book stating why this happened.  Anybody know the answer to this?

> "Haven't you ever had a Sprite before?"
>   "No."
>   She rolled her eyes as she cleaned herself. "I know, you stick to beer."
>   Ash didn't answer as he took a deep draft of it again. **He frowned as a strange wave of dizziness went through his head. If he didn't know better, he'd think he was getting a buzz from it. But that was impossible. As a god, he didn't get drunk. And even if he did, there was nothing in soda that would intoxicate him.**
>
> She handed him another bottle. "Are you drunk?"
>
> **"I feel drunk."**

Answer (score 1):

The next part of the quote is quite enlightening; After having engaged in what can only be described as **appallingly badly written sex** he claims that he is *intoxicated by her presence*;

> "I'm drunk on your beauty. Look what you've done to me, human"

Shortly afterward, he takes the (slightly odd) decision to reveal his godhood to her and completely blows his cover by performing a range of minor miracles.

I'd suggest that it was never the *Sprite* that made him drunk, it was simply that she'd boinked him into a stupor.

Comment: That's not really the case, considering in the book he's had plenty of sex with people... being that he used to be a sex slave.  Tory was somehow connected to him in a way that was not yet revealed in the story until the very end, but it seems like somehow the Sprite had gotten him drunk,  I believe he only said that line because he was drunk in the first place.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - Based on the small portion I had the misfortune to read, I can confidently say that the answer is almost certainly *poor writing*

Comment: The overall book was interesting, I just felt that the portion where he gets drunk might actually be poor writing, if anything it could be that someone had tampered with the Sprite.  If anything it could possibly have been his mother Apollymi but I don't remember seeing any evidence of her doing so... The only interference she's made was to make the Apollites in the book become Daimons by showing them how to circumvent Apollo's curse of them dying at the age of 27.  Also making sure Tory doesn't sleep with anybody else.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - You might try contacting the author. She seems very new-media savvy and has a twitter/facebook/pinterest page you could ask her on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual answer to this question as it appears to be a plot hole, not part of Dark Hunter canon.

Edited to add: I'm not just speculating, I've read all of her books twice including Acheron but have found no information to explain this incident.

Comment: Although you may be right (in that it's not explained further in the books) that doesn't mean that the author didn't have a definite reason for putting it in.

Comment: In that case then she would likely have elaborated on it at a further point, or it would have been important to the plot which it wasn't. She is known for occasionally glossing over details so this would not be the first time or something she does not do consistently.

Comment: That may well be, but unless you're the author (or have some other privileged info), simply waving your hand at something that definitely happened in the novel and saying "the author didn't mean to put that" is speculation, at best.

Comment: That's why I said "it appears to be a plot hole". I'm not saying what is in the authors head but how it can be interpreted based on the consistency (or lack there of) of her other 30 books.